# addEventListener after appendChild

Tags: javascript, dom

I create an element, `eltTooltip`, with `document.createElement` etc and add it to the DOM like this (`idTooltip` contains the `id` of `eltTooltip`):

```
document.body.appendChild(eltTooltip);
var addedElt = document.getElementById(idTooltip);
addedElt.addEventListener("click", function(){...});
```

Is the `click` event guaranteed to be added here, or is perhaps the DOM not ready for that?

Could I do this in a better way? (The page is loaded long ago so `window.onload` can not be used. And I can't use jQuery here.)

Comment: You don't need `getElementById`; you can use the variable you stored it in when you created it.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. I just did a copy and paste from some different parts of my code... ;-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your way works perfectly fine but it's probably better to attach the event listener before you add it to the DOM using `eltTooltip`. This saves you from fetching the element from the DOM.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6QDX/1/)

```
var idTooltip = 'test';
var eltTooltip = document.createElement('div');
eltTooltip.innerHTML = "test"
eltTooltip.setAttribute('id', idTooltip);
eltTooltip.addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert('click');
});

document.body.appendChild(eltTooltip);
```

Comment: Thanks Dainiel and @SLaks. Where did you find information about this?

Comment: The main problem was that you were fetching the element again using `document.getElementById`. Putting `addEventListener` being adding it to the DOM is more of a code cleanliness thing (finalise messing with the element before adding it), it should work if you attach after calling `appendChild` too.

Comment: A mistake of course, I am not very good at cleaning up code. ;-) -- I guess you are right. I have not seen any strange problem with code like this for quite a while now.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
window.onload = function (){
    var toolTip = document.createElement('div');
    toolTip.innerHTML = "someData";
    toolTip.addEventListener('click', myfunction);
    document.body.appendChild(toolTip);

    function myfunction(){
        alert("hello guys ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Suman. (This is the third time I am entering this commment. Wonder why it disappears?)

Comment: You are wel come. Now I can see it, vote the answer is good way to thank.