# set onclick event to <li> in javascript

Tags: html-lists

I have a dynamic list, which adds items as they load.

```
<ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>
```

Please see function addItem()

What I need to do is an event to be fired when an item is selected from the ordered list.

Since I don't have a < li> tag, I can't set onclick in this.

There is a way to add or set in the javascript document that each il has an onclick event?

document.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Dynamically add/remove items from list - JavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>

    <input type="text" id="candidate"/>
    <button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
    <button onclick="removeItem()">remove item</button>

    <p id="textoprueba"></p>

   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function addItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
    var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.setAttribute('id',candidate.value);
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
    var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
    var item = document.getElementById(candidate.value);
    ul.removeChild(item);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [addEventListener after appendChild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21292657/addeventlistener-after-appendchild)

Answer (score 0):

You can always add the button inside the list item and use css to align and justify the content later.

```
<li>
  <span>List item text</span>
  <button onclick="removeItem()">button</button>
</li>
```

Or even wrap your entire list item in a button container, this is not really intuitive and not the best choice design-wise.

```
<button onclick="removeItem()">
  <li>List item text</li>
</button>
```

Just remember to pass the id of the list item on your remove function.